# How to create a requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I'm wondering how I can create a suitable requirements.txt for my Python 3 application?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

type following line in your command prompt

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: This answer will work *assuming you are using virtualenv*.

Comment: It will work even if not using a `virtualenv`, but it will list all packages installed on the system with pip

Comment: Even if it works, it is too clumsy and blotted. Suppose you have 100 libraries you need in a project. And with 3 dependencies each. Will you be able to manage your requirements.txt?

Answer (score 47):

There's a module called pipreqs which is designed for creating the requirements file.

```
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs /GitHub/FolderName #Insert path to file
```

Add the location to the folder where the python files reside. Pipreqs will create a requirements.txt file in the folder.

Comment: Thanks! This also works great (it doesn't add all the libraries in a machine, but only those used in the folder), even if you don't have a virtual environment!

Comment: This doesn't catch all possible cascading dependencies for my Cython lib, but it's the starting point I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

if you aren't in virtualenv and don't feel like putting all your installed packages in the requirements file like the accepted answer. just use [pigar](https://github.com/Damnever/pigar)

Comment: To be clear you simply install pigar and run `pigar` in the local directory of the python file you want the requirements.txt for