# How To Check If A Python Package Is Defaultly Installed Or Do We Have To Install It Using PIP

Tags: python, pip

I Have A Project Which Uses Many Python Libraries And I Want To Share This Project With My Friends And Many Others. But, I Don't Know If Their Computers Will Have Those Packages Installed On Their Computers. So I Wanted To Make A **requirements.txt** File. When `pip install requirements.txt` Is Run It Will Automatically Installs The Uninstalled Packages.

I Want To Put The Names Of The Packages Which Are Deafautly Not Installed Such As Kivy, Matplotlib, Numpy.
Some Default Installed Packages Are Random etc. So I Don't Want To Put These Names In The **requirements.txt** File.

Please Help Me Out On This.
Thank You!!

Comment: Just do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Voila.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a requirements.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938554/how-to-create-a-requirements-txt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt)

Comment: @Czaporka Got The Answer In The Question Link You Provided. Didn't See Such Questions Before Asking One Myself. Sorry For The Inconvenience Caused To Anyone.
Thank You For The Answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you aren't using virtual environments. You can create a virtual environment for your Python package on your machine.
The process is very simple. Please follow the official Python documentation for setting up a virtual env for your project. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Test the package inside this virtualenv. This would require you to install all the required dependencies inside this virtualenv.

From here you can run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

to generate the `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: This Generates A Requirements.txt File For All The Extra Modules You Have Installed On Your Computer. So You Have To Make A Virtual Environment Then Put Your Files In There And Then Run This Again. Which Takes A Lot Of Time. But, Thanks For The Effort You Put Into Providing This Answer.

Comment: I understand that using virtualenvs seems like an extra hurdle but using them to isolate dependencies is an established best practice for python projects.

Answer (score -1):

Try this , it will print all modules

```
help('modules')
```